# Metaprogramação com ruby , métodos com SELF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramação, self

boa noite... eu venho de outras linguagens um tanto diferente ao Ruby, como C/C++ , JAVA... E me perdi um pouco ao tentar entender a diferença dos seguintes métodos:

```
Class teste 
     def novo
       "1"
     end
     def self.testenovo
     "2"
     end
end
```

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os dois métodos... eu andei pesquisando e vi que self é um método da classe e o "novo" é um método de instância... isso se aplica aonde ? em tempo de execução apenas certo ? pois ao fazermos isso e declararmos uma variavel instanciada da classe teste, ela terá os dois métodos, correto ? então onde se aplica esse tipo de declaração ?  Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Rafael! Eu vi que você colocou "metaprogramação" na sua pergunta, e minha resposta terminou não falando disso - ela responde as dúvidas que você colocou no corpo da pergunta. Talvez seja interessante você fazer uma nova pergunta, i.e. "qual a utilidade do self na metaprogramação?" ou algo parecido - pode trazer respostas mais interessantes! Ah, e seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digamos que você esteja escrevendo um programa sobre carros, e, sabendo que estamos em 2017, [faltam apenas dois anos para os carros voarem](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner).

Seu programa então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
class Carro
  @@voa = false # carros não podem voar ainda

  def self.voa(v) # nosso setter pra quando carros puderem voar
    @@voa = v
  end

  def initialize(marca)
    @marca = marca
  end

  def explica
    if @@voa
      print 'eu sou um ' + @marca.to_s + ' e eu posso voar!'
    else
      print 'eu sou um ' + @marca.to_s + ' e eu nao posso voar ainda! :('
    end
  end
end
```

> `def self.voa(v)`, permite que nós modifiquemos a variável `@@voa`, que é uma variável de `classe`, então se aplica a todas as instâncias.

Vamos criar alguns carros:

```
carros = []
carros << Carro.new('chevrolet')
carros << Carro.new('ford')
carros << Carro.new('volkswagen')
carros << Carro.new('fiat')
```

E chamamos o método `explica` de cada um deles:

```
carros.each { |c| puts c.explica }
```

Saída:

```
eu sou um chevrolet e eu nao posso voar ainda! :(
eu sou um ford e eu nao posso voar ainda! :(
eu sou um volkswagen e eu nao posso voar ainda! :(
```

Agora quando chegarmos em 2019, podemos simplesmente chamar:

```
Carro.voa(true) # chama pela classe!
```

Todos os nossos carros se tornam *spinners*, uhul!

```
eu sou um chevrolet e eu posso voar!
eu sou um ford e eu posso voar!
eu sou um volkswagen e eu posso voar!
eu sou um fiat e eu posso voar!
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/IkRJ).

### Um Exemplo Melhor

Como estamos falando de um `método de classe`, é possível usá-lo para guardar todas as instâncias criadas na própria classe:

```
class Pessoa
  # variável de classe, onde guardaremos nossas instâncias
  @@pessoas = Array.new
  attr_accessor :nome

  def self.lista_pessoas
    @@pessoas
  end

  def initialize(nome)
    @nome = nome
    # ao instanciar, já guardamos no array
    @@pessoas << self
  end
end

# criando algumas pessoas
pessoa_1 = Pessoa.new('Ana')
pessoa_2 = Pessoa.new('Julia')
pessoa_3 = Pessoa.new('Tatiana')

# e listando todas, à partir do método de classe
Pessoa.lista_pessoas.each { |p| puts p.nome }
```

Veja funcionando no [repl.it](https://repl.it/IkSZ).

[Exemplo tirado daqui.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532844/ruby-array-of-objects-classes)